# VS2017 setup - wrong team services account used?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

Newbe to Team Services...

Vs2015 Desktop Community for original setup.

I stumbled through the setup of our ...visualstudio.com account and it is working on two PCs. I went down the GIT path but I'm not really clear on the process, I just kept banging on it until it worked. It is working (mostly) for two VB.Net WinForm projects on two PCs.

I'm now setting up a brand new PC and I installed VS2017. I didn't install any extra software for GIT (can't find any directions for source control install for that either, [TS GIT quick start](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart-vs2017) doesn't mention setting up GIT) I logged into the visualstudio cloud from the new install and cloned one of the projects from the cloud GUI. The files came down OK but the project type is evidently wrong because the Solution Explorer always lists all files and I can't open a form in the GUI. I also tried to use VS2017 to clone/download the project with the same result.

**Do I need to install GIT in a fresh install of VS2017? Download from where/how to get a proper hookup with VS2017?**

**Why am I getting the files OK but the project type is not VB.Net Winform? Can that be tweaked or should I start over?**

I was able to download using the .zip option from visualstudio.com but it isn't connected to a local or cloud repository. I'm not sure it is a good idea to connect these "out of band" files to an exisitng repository. The project is of the correct type and it builds OK and works.

Thanks!

---

View of solution in broken project:[image]

Comment: What's the VS version installed on the two PCs which works? And did you compared the downloaded files in that two PCs with the files on the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s unnecessary to install extra software after you installed VS2017.

In short, use VS to work with git repo on VSTS (visual studio team services), you just need to **connect your VSTS account** in VS and **clone a local repo** as working copy for VSTS git repo. Operations in VS 2017 should be:

1. Connect your VSTS account in VS2017.

   VS2017 -> team explorer -> manage connections -> connect to project. 
   [image]

   If your VSTS account (sign up email address) hasn’t connected yet, click add an account. After that, you can select your VSTS project/repo to connect/clone.

   [image]
2. Clone VSTS git repo locally.

   If you didn’t clone git repo in step1, then right click a VSTS repo -> clone.
   [image]
3. Work on the local repo.

   After successfully cloned a repo, you are working on the local repo, you can also find the local repo’s name and branch you are working for in the right bottom of VS2017. Now the solutions should be same as what you find in VSTS.

   [image]

   And you can make change and commit for them. And then push your local commit(s) to VSTS git repo.

---

For VS2017, there are **two forms to view solutions and files**: solution related and all files/folders.

[image]

If you can’t find `.Designer.vb` and `.resx` files, you must use the second mode as the above graph.

To view all files/folder, you can switch the view to first mode as below graph.

[image]

Comment: Those are the steps I took but it failed to work properly as indicated in the OP.

Comment: In general the steps above worked but the project is unusable as a VB.Net WinForms project. In a properly formed WinForms project each for has one entry in the Solution Explorer and the designer and resources files are hidden until the Show All Files is engaged. In the fresh download the All File view is the only view.

Comment: The solution explorer is showing the files (not sure about the .sln file, I don't have access at the moment.) Try this - create a new VB.net (C# should work too) WinForm project. In the solution explorer you will see one form Form1.vb. There are actually three files that make up Form1: .vb, .designer.vb, and optionally .res. If you use Show All the underlying files appear. In the cloned project it is stuck on the Show All file list. Also, in a proper poject a double click on Form.vb opens the designer, in the cloned project the form cannot be opened. Wrong template obviously.

Comment: Added screen shot - "all files" view is the only view. From cannot be opened in the GUI.

Comment: I updated my answer, please find it in the last part ;)

Comment: The `Solutions and Folders` icon did the trick! WinForms project now works as expected.